# jQuery Toggle Slide Wrong Direction

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I have a fully functioning jFiddle that is working well for me... however, I'm wondering if someone could point out to me what changes need to be made to have the text appear BELOW the button clicked... Currently the button clicked slides down and is underneath the text - I'd really like for the text to be what slides DOWN from the logo.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/LHcgp/142/

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$(".more").hide();
$('.button-read-more').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.less').addClass('active');
    $(this).closest(".less").prev().stop(true).slideDown("1000");
    });
$('.button-read-less').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.less').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest(".less").prev().stop(true).slideUp("1000");
    });
});
```

Comment: jsFiddle is password protected.

Comment: Disabled now - my apologies.

Comment: Is the structure of the HTML flexible or set the way it is?

Comment: I don't really care what I have to change/edit, etc just in order to get the effect I want. So... everything is flexible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're free to modify the HTML, you could move the text below your image

From this:

```
<div class="more" style="display:none">
    <p align="justify">Our full service real estate brokerage, Brooks Realty, carries on a decades-spanning legacy of serving Northwest Florida's Emerald Coast with "Everything in Real Estate"</p>
</div>

<div class="less">
    <a class="button-read-more button-read" href="#read"><img src="http://test.southernventures.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/svc_home_brk.png"></a>
    <a class="button-read-less button-read" href="#read"><img src="http://test.southernventures.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/svc_home_brk_color.png"></a>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="less">
    <a class="button-read-more button-read" href="#read"><img src="http://test.southernventures.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/svc_home_brk.png"></a>
    <a class="button-read-less button-read" href="#read"><img src="http://test.southernventures.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/svc_home_brk_color.png"></a>
</div>
    <div class="more" style="display:none">
    <p align="justify">Our full service real estate brokerage, Brooks Realty, carries on a decades-spanning legacy of serving Northwest Florida's Emerald Coast with "Everything in Real Estate"</p>
</div>
```

And then update your JavaScript to look for the `next` element, rather than the `prev`.

So this:

```
    $(this).closest(".less").prev().stop(true).slideDown("1000");
```

Becomes

```
    $(this).closest(".less").next().stop(true).slideUp("1000");
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LHcgp/154/